# Querying on DATE field

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, date

I would like to query the details of reports which will expire between specific dates. The expiration dates are filled in manually.

E.g. give me the reports which will expire between 01-11-2016 and 30-11-2016

I store the expiration dates as strings in the database; however, when I query on them I do not get the correct results.

I am wondering using the DATE type instead of string would give correct results..

Comment: Of course date type should be used for dates! BTW, tag the dbms used.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)